# Unable to locate an element within a table using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

Table content is not being loaded using selenium webdriver. It displays only headers of the table but not the content.

I have logged in successfully in my application but on the home screen there is a table with certain project listed, while using selenium it does not load the content in the table.

**Selenium jars:** 2.53
**Mozilla Firefox version :** 46.0

Used google chrome browser for the same but it didn't work too.

When I close the browser (Which selenium opened) and reopened it manually, it works fine. But when selenium opens it and go to home page, table data does not load.

```
 <div class="project-list-bg" _ngcontent-c1="">
<div class="col s12 project-container" _ngcontent-c1="">
<main _ngcontent-c1="">
<div class="col s12 search-block" _ngcontent-c1="">
<div class="search-wrapper" _ngcontent-c1="">
<label _ngcontent-c1="">Search: </label>
<div class="card" _ngcontent-c1="">
<input class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" type="text" _ngcontent-c1="" name="search">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<table id="myTable" class="bordered centered " _ngcontent-c1="">
<thead _ngcontent-c1="">
<tr _ngcontent-c1="">
<th class="grey-text text-darken-1" width="10%" _ngcontent-c1="">
Project ID
<i class="material-icons" _ngcontent-c1="">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
</th>
<th class="grey-text text-darken-1" width="17%" _ngcontent-c1="">
Project Name
<i class="material-icons" _ngcontent-c1="">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
</th>
<th class="grey-text text-darken-1" _ngcontent-c1="" style="width: 12%;">
Date Completed
<i class="material-icons" _ngcontent-c1="">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
</th>
<th class="grey-text text-darken-1" width="10%" _ngcontent-c1="" style="background-image: none; ">
# of Runs
<i class="material-icons" _ngcontent-c1="">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
</th>
<th class="grey-text text-darken-1" width="10%" _ngcontent-c1="" style="background-image: none; ">
Status
<i class="material-icons" _ngcontent-c1="">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
</th>
<th class="grey-text text-darken-1" width="16%" _ngcontent-c1="" style="background-image: none; ">
Project Description
<i class="material-icons" _ngcontent-c1="">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
</th>
<th width="12%" _ngcontent-c1="" style="background-image: none; "></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody _ngcontent-c1="">
</table>
<div class="pagination right-align" _ngcontent-c1="">
<pagination-controls _ngcontent-c1="">
<pagination-template>
<ul class="ngx-pagination" role="navigation" aria-label="Pagination">
</pagination-template>
</pagination-controls>
</div>
<div class="row" _ngcontent-c1="">
<div class="col s6 add-btn2 left-align" _ngcontent-c1="">
<a _ngcontent-c1="" routerlink="/project-information" href="/project-information">
<button class="btn next-btn p-btn" _ngcontent-c1=""> Add Project</button>
</a>
</div>
<div class="col s6 right-align" _ngcontent-c1="">
<ul id="myPager" class="pagination pager" _ngcontent-c1=""></ul>
</div>
</div>
</main>
</div>
</div>
```

------------Selenium Code----------------------------------

```
package projectListingScreen;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import ObjectRepository.HomescreenObject;
import ObjectRepository.PageObject;
import loginScreen.LoginPage;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class HomeScreen extends LoginPage {

    public WebDriver driver;

  @Test
  public void f() {

         WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
          WebElement addprojectbutton;
          addprojectbutton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath( "html/body/app-root/app-home/div/div/main/div[3]/div[1]/a/button")));
          addprojectbutton.click();

  }
```

I have to click this `<button>` element but if the table(HTML of the table you can find in comments) does not load properly then this button moves upward and selenium is unable to find this button and in return it gives null pointer exception.

Comment: Please show the HTML of your table

Comment: share the relevant HTML.

Comment: <table id="myTable" class="bordered centered " _ngcontent-c2="">
<thead _ngcontent-c2="">
<tr _ngcontent-c2="">
<th class="grey-text text-darken-1" width="10%" _ngcontent-c2="">
Project ID
<i class="material-icons" _ngcontent-c2="">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
</th>
<th class="grey-text text-darken-1" width="17%" _ngcontent-c2="">
Project Name
<i class="material-icons" _ngcontent-c2="">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
</th>

Comment: <button class="btn next-btn p-btn" _ngcontent-c2=""> Add Project</button>
I have to click this button but if the above table does not load properly then this button moves upward and selenium is unable to find this button and in return it gives null pointer exception.

Comment: @Abhishek Instead of comments edit the main question with this information.

Comment: @DebanjanB: Done...Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Abhishek I have accomodated the HTML from your first comment within the question. I am not sure how and where the `<button class="btn next-btn p-btn" _ngcontent-c2=""> Add Project</button>` is placed with respect to the currently updated HTML. Feel free to correct the HTML

Comment: @DebanjanB: Please check the updated HTML now...and share if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

To click on this `<button>` with text as **Add Project**, as the *AUT* contains *Angular* elements you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following line of code :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn next-btn p-btn'][normalize-space()='Add Project']"))).click();
```

Comment: That's exactly what I tried to  do earlier but it didn't work...
 WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    WebElement addprojectbutton;
    addprojectbutton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath( "html/body/app-root/app-home/div/div/main/div[3]/div[1]/a/button")));
    addprojectbutton.click();

Comment: @Abhishek `didn't work` doesn't throws any light on whats wrong happening. Update the question with your current _code trial_ and _error stack trace_

Comment: @Abhishek That is not exactly the solution which I have provided. Copy-paste the exact code (solution) and update us (or the question) the status.

Comment: You want me to share the selenium code or the complete HTML..??

Comment: Edit and Update the main question with your actual code trial

Comment: I have put both the files i.e. java file and HTML file. Just check if you can help me with the same.

Comment: Any update you got on this..??..coz I am unable to find out why it is throwing Null Pointer Exception...